# Creating groups with an android app

Tags: android, google-groups

I'm working on an app, one of the feature I am interested in is the "Groups". I should be able to create groups within my app using some existing api, (google groups for example), I should be able to add friends from my google account.When I do so, I want some notification to be sent, so that my friends can accept the invite and be a part of the group. Can this be made with the app?

Comment: So the notification can be sent within the app ?